# Mid-1990s novel about young programmer who gets into trouble in Dallas

Tags: identification-request

Novel about a **talented young computer programmer** (maybe a child-protege..?) who makes a splash in the programming world and ends up moving to Dallas. I don’t really remember much of the plot, but I think he ends up getting in some trouble there because of Dallas’ “incomparable nightlife”.

The **“incomparable Dallas nightlife”** might not be an exact quote, but I think it’s pretty close. Didn’t work in any of the book-finder search engines I tried though.

I think it was written sometime **around 1995** - but might be two or three years off - either earlier or, more probably, a little later.

It was a **novel**, not a non-fiction book about computers or programming, although I seem to remember the author included quite a lot of material about both. This was about the time that computers and the internet were really starting to take off, and I think the author wanted to show how cool the computer industry was becoming.

This was probably not a book released by a big, well-known publisher - but I don't know that for sure either.

I’m guessing **the book probably didn't sell very well**.

Not a lot to go on.

I've been impressed with how well people on this site are able to identify things with very little information, but I'll be very impressed if someone comes up with this one.